# Web-Based Virtual Machine Manager

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, virtual-machines, libvirt

I am looking for a web-based virtual machine manager, which will work on our Ubuntu server.
Ideally, I need something that our team can use to create a VM, test builds and packaging and then either restore to the original state or delete.

libvirt has an API, but I can't find any web apps using it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use opennebula or eucalyptus.

See also the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/9.04/serverguide/C/virtualization.html) at Ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you're looking for [oVirt](http://ovirt.org/). It uses libvirt.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at proxmox VE http://www.proxmox.com webbased control of your virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

VMware Server 2 has a web-based admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at [Redhat's virt-manager](http://virt-manager.et.redhat.com), though it is not web-based.